# How to make a method in a subslass in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I want to make methods +square() and setSide(side : double): void

please help me in this regard.  [image]

Comment: What help do you need, specifically?

Comment: You create a method in a subclass just like you do in any class.

Comment: Ask yourself this, what makes a square different from a rectangle?

Comment: How to make +square() , AND I can not make  +Square(side: double) : void   , and understand mean by :void

Comment: Are you saying you need someone to write those methods for you?

Comment: And `:void` just means that those methods don't return any value.

Comment: Did you make `+Rectangle()` already?  I imagine `+Square()` would be similar.

Answer (score 1):

A square has sides all the same length, so when we use the variables/methods inherited from the rectangle class, we must make sure to apply them to both width and length.

The constructor:

```
public Square() {
    super();
}
```

The set side:

```
public void setSide(double side) {
    super.setWidth(side);
    super.setLength(side);
}
```

Since the values of the rectangle are set to default values we can use the default constructor. Since we have to make sure all sides are the same length, both width and length have to be updated. Equally, you could get away with only using one, and modifying the functions accordingly. Say for width:

```
public void setSide(double side) {
    super.setWidth(side);
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for your help !  your code solved my problem